# how to organize structures for a mobile app for cross platform usage in phonegap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, cordova, backbone.js, project-management

i'd like to build a simply application with rails that will include the backend and with json response for a backbone.js app that will integrate the ui framework of jquery-mobile

(inspired on this [article](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/employee-directory-sample-app-with-backbone-js-and-jquery-mobile/) and the videocasts of [ryan bates's site](http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1?autoplay=true))

before i'm doing something complitely wrong i'd like to ask you if is better:

to build the backbone.js/jquery-mobile application apart rails structure but with the eco template for a better integration with phonegap for publish the app on the apple store

or

is it possible to mantain all the structures all togheter with the  [backbone-on-rails gem](http://backbone-on-rails%20gem) like ryan had illustrated in the 2 videos and after compile all with phonegap with specific steps?

i hope that the question is quite clear!

Answer (score 1):

I would personally familiarize myself with one of the two first and then port my knowledge to integrate the second.
First, it would be a good idea to keep Rails as your server REST API and database. You can develop your app with backbone and Rails just like you saw Ryan do.
Second, once you are familiar with Backbone and your structure is working, it should be much easier to take everything and compile a simple application using PhoneGap.
One step at a time, better testing, better understanding.